# How to save blanks on a numeric field, not zeros

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have a column in the grid as follows:

```
 drNew[TableColumns.Column_OTCNonCover] = item.OTC_NON_COVER.ToDecimal();
```

the thing is, it's numeric data, Financial amounts. However, if the user does not enter, we want the col to have blanks, not zeros saves as is currently happening.

Can this be coded for that?

Comment: Actually, a nullable decimal - decimal? - is what you want. I assume that the corresponding column in the database is nullable.#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you cannot have an empty number, what you are trying to do is a contradiction. The best approach would be to use a `string` rather than a `decimal` and convert afterwards.

However, you will lose some of the advantages of validating a numeric field.

Comment: You can have an empty number. Nullable types are what's required.

Comment: I would argue that would be a `null` number, not an empty one; but agreed, given the presentation it might be the better choice.

Comment: And it will appear as a blank in the grid he uses too. Cheers -